# Are there any (free) games databases out there?

Tags: database

I am searching for a broad and extensive games database (i.e. games played between real players.)

I can hardly seem to find any (even paid ones.) - However all sorts of chess software has these built in.

Where can I get my hands on one?

I will use it for a lot of analyses on different players, openings etc.

Hope someone can help me out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [pretty big one](http://www.openingmaster.com/index.php/subscribe/membership) if you are willing to spend some 40 euro.

[This (Million Base 2.2)](http://www.top-5000.nl/pgn.htm) is the biggest free database I know of.

Answer (score 7):

These databases could be interesting for you:

- The Week In Chess (=[TWIC](http://www.theweekinchess.com/twic)) (free): updated every week, PGN format
- Mega Database of [ChessBase](https://shop.chessbase.com/en/cat_root) (commercial): requires the ChessBase gui
- Huge Database of [ChessOK](http://chessok.com/shop/) (commercial): requires the ChessAssistant gui

Answer (score 5):

In addition to very good suggestions in the previous answers, you might also be interested in [Pgnmentor's site](http://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html) (free).

There you already have free databases sorted according to players and openings, as well as events (tournament, matches etc.). Of course, you can easily produce such thematic games collections from big databases mentioned in other answers, but still, I find separated databases pretty convenient (e.g. for themed research).

Answer (score 2):

There is a combination of PGN Mentor and TWIC files: http://gorgonian.weebly.com/pgn.html

Comment: It's not PGN -- it's in SCID format

Comment: Yes, but I said PGN mentor not PGN format

Comment: Yes but I'm just pointing this out to people so they can know.  I actually downloaded the thing in the hopes I can convert it to PGN format.

Answer (score 2):

ChessTempo.com has recently added a new functionality - a database. All the options are described in the user guide at http://chesstempo.com/user-guide/en/chessDatabase.html

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of PGN file database download sites, the best and most comprehensive one is probably PGN Mentor at

https://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html

BUT...very few have annotated game collections, so I have put about 950 annotated games, which are in 9 separate ".pgn" files, here

[Annotated PGN file download page](https://pgnchessbook.org/pgn/)

for people to download

Answer (score 2):

- [15 million games in misc databases on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/codekiddy-chess/files/)
- [Kings Base by Pierre Havard](http://www.kingbase-chess.net/)
- [Gorgonians big game collection](http://gorgonian.weebly.com/pgn.html)
- [Misc Collections someone scraped from chessgames.com](http://smallchess.com/Games/)
- [TWIC latest games downloads](https://theweekinchess.com/twic)

Answer (score 1):

I have some special prepared PGN files for my chess apps. You can download those files:

[World Chess Championship](http://smallchess.com/Games/World%20Championship.pgn)

[Magnus Carlsen](http://smallchess.com/Games/Magnus%20Carlsen.pgn)

[J.R Capablanca](http://smallchess.com/Games/Jose%20Raul%20Capablanca.pgn)

The download site is [here](http://smallchess.com/Games/), please note the purpose of the site is to provide easy-to-download games for my iOS app users.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of databases out there. http://chessgames.com, http://pgnmentor.com, etc. Check http://www.chessfiles.com/chess-database.html for other databases